NC switch creating a connection to GND when open
I have a potentiometer with a built-in independent switch. The switch is closed in most situations, but when you go all the way counterclockwise the switch opens and I want this to turn off a device.
The device has an EN pin that, when pulled to GND will shut off the device. I was thinking that I would make a circuit with an NPN transistor that would have the emitter connected to GND but it didn't work.

The EN pin is on a SparkFun ESP32 Thing Plus (USB-C). The EN pin controls the 3.3V regulator that supplies the ESP32 chip's power. The actual EN pin is held high with an internal connection to VIN with a 10k resistor. From the schematic:

Is there a different way to accomplish this? Essentially, how can I use a switch the, when open, pulls a pin to GND.

If you want to turn the device off when the switch is open then you need a different configuration. Right now, when the switch is open, EN gets pulled high. Please post datasheets so we can better advise you on a solution that will do what you want.

Your circuit will pull the EN pin to Ground when the switch is closed.
Try this to pull the EN to Ground with the switch open:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Any handy NPN transistor will do...

If your transistor's Vce(sat) is higher than the enable pin's Vil, then a MOSFET like a 2N7000 might be called for. Unlikely, but possible.

A MOSFET is also better because zero current draw while the device is off, depending on the battery that 0.1mA may be important.

If I understand the OP correctly, the switch is embedded into the VAR, so there is no way to tap off from between the resistor part and the switch part.

I had a BC184L on hand and it doesn't seem to be working... but I am trying some other things based on this and other feedback.

@vir The Vce is considered low at 0.3V I believe. The datasheet is at https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/642/XC6222.pdf for the power regulator.

@MikeB The resistor was added by me, sorry for the confusion.

@thaimin  so where is the "inline" resistor that is bonded to the switch?

Turns out the transistor I had on hand was faulty. Received new ones and now it is working.

Assuming the enable pin can witstand a reasonable external voltage source
Just use a pull down

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You forgot to mention that they have to remove the resistor R8 from the pre-assembled module, otherwise it will create a mid-rail voltage (actually slightly below because the regulator already includes a ~250K pull-down).

@TomV Can you explain more? Otherwise this circuit seems to be working, but I would like to understand any side-effects that I am missing. For example, I would like to understand what the vampire current (?) is and how long the battery would last when off.

R8 on the sparkfun schematic will pull EN up by 10K, this will pull it down by the same amount.  You just have to de-populate R8, and connect the point labelled VCC in this answer to one end of where it was and EN from the answer to the the other end of where you have removed it.

Note: having 10K up and 10K down will actually waste less current than just 10K down, and half-rail voltage is well above VceH, so this will still work, but it would be more usual to avoid creating mid-rail voltages.  You can also save power by using a bigger resister than 10K.

I did not forget.  that informationm was not available at the time

but yeah, remove R8 and connect the switch, and a series 10K  in it's place.

With a 1K resistor, this works (even with R8 in there). Higher values don't work consistently. Now I just need to figure out how to remove the SMD resistor from a fairly high-density area...

use a wide tip and put lots of solder on top of it and it will stick to your soldering iron.
